# How to render hasMany associations each with their own controller

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

So my models are set up like this :

```
App.Post = DS.Model.extend
  comments: DS.hasMany 'App.Comment'

App.Comment = DS.Model.extend
  post: DS.belongsTo 'App.Post'
```

I'm trying to create a view that has all posts and all comments display, but I need to decorate the comment objects.

This is what I'd like to do but, to no avail :

```
<ul>
  {{#each post in controller}}
    <li>{{post.title}}</li>
    <ol>
      {{#each comment in post.comments itemController="comment"}}
        <li>{{comment.body}}</li>
      {{/each}}
    </ol>
  {{/each}}
</ul>
```

Properties defined in a `App.CommentController` are simply not found by the template.

I suspect that `Ember.OrderedSet` does not implement the `itemController` param - is there a workaround for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the new expiremental control tag. This will load the view and controller for the specified type:

```
<ul>
  {{#each post in controller}}
    <li>{{post.title}}</li>
    <ol>
      {{#each comment in post.comments}}
        {{ control "comment" comment }}
      {{/each}}
    </ol>
  {{/each}}
</ul>
```

You will need to enable this expiremental feature first. Put this before ember is loaded:

```
<script type='application/javascript'>
    ENV = {
        EXPERIMENTAL_CONTROL_HELPER: true
    };
</script>
```

Also, you will need to specify that the controller for comments should not be a singleton, otherwise there will only be one controller instantiated for all comment views:

```
// this is needed to use control handlebars template properly per
// https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/1990
App.register('controller:comment', App.CommentController, {singleton: false });
```

Comment: Great answer buuda, thanks! It's worth noting that `itemController` is not necessary when using `control`.